# How to join multiple columns from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called `FieldList` that looks like this:

```
ElementName|Description|comp_id|FieldName
-----------------------------------------
Name       | red       | 1     | names  
Name       | blue      | 7     | names  
field      | red       | 1     | names  
boxes      | blue      | 5     | blues  
field      | orange    | 7     | reds
```

And I want to show a new table that shows only the `ElementNames` that are the same and then show which `comp_id` they belong to so it looks like this:

```
ElementName| comp_id| comp_id
-----------------------------
Name       | 1      | 7  
field      | 1      | 7
```

It doesnt have to look exactly like this but the point is I want to be able to join and show the `ElementNames` that are identical but have different `comp_id`'s. 
This is the little bit of sql code that I have already but its obviously not working.

```
SELECT a.comp_id, a.ElementName, b.ElementName  
FROM FieldList a  
INNER JOIN FieldList b ON a.ElementName = b.ElementName;
```

Comment: How many similar element names could there be?  If the max number is not know, then you would need dynamic SQL to solve this.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: This is equivalent to "select a.comp_id, a.elementName from..." without the join.  It is an equijoin on itself.  If you have a finite number of values, or you know there is logically an upper limit you can construct a query to satisfy.  I would be happy to show this solution if you can give me an idea of how many possible elementName values there are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT a.ElementName, a.comp_id, b.comp_id  
From FieldList a  
left join FieldList b on 
     a.ElementName = b.ElementName and
     a.comp_id <> b.comp_id
WHERE a.comp_id is not null
```

Comment: I think you mean: SELECT a.ElementName, a.comp_id, b.comp_id... You don't want to repeat the Element Name when below you have it as a condition that they are a.ElementName = b.ElementName

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want element names that have the same comp ids.  If so, you can use `group_concat()` like this:

```
select group_concat(elementname), comps
from (select fl.elementname, group_concat(fl.comp_id order by fl.comp_id) as comps
      from fieldlist fl
      group by fl.elementname
     ) en
group by comps;
```

This actually produces rows with two lists:

```
Name,field     1,7
```

But it seems to contain the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

This query may accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT a.ElementName, a.comp_id, b.comp_id
    FROM FieldList a
    JOIN FieldList b ON a.ElementName = b.ElementName
    WHERE a.comp_id != b.comp_id
    GROUP BY a.ElementName, (a.comp_id + b.comp_id);
```

Note that I am grouping by the addition of the two comp_ids. If I didn't, you wouldn't get rows for each duplication.